# Minecraft add player to team based on scoreboard score

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a player join a team when their score is a specific number.

Example:
/scoreboard teams join Rank1 @a[score_ranklvl=1]

Basically, if the players level equals a number and only that specific number will the player join that team.

Answer (score 1):

The command for adding players to teams is:

```
scoreboard teams join [teamname] [players]
```

And the code that means "all players" is @a

That means, to add everyone to a team we do

```
scoreboard teams join <teamname> @a
```

All we need to do is add a modifier to @a to accomplish what you want
You had it right, but you were saying when there score is a maximum of one.
This is the command you would use:

```
scoreboard teams join Rank1 @a[score_ranklvl_min=1, score_ranklvl=1]
```